# Unable to remove cached page in Symfony 2.6

Tags: php, symfony, caching

I am experiencing a weird behaviour with Symfony 2.6

I have a page that lists my users and its routing is in routing.yml as follows:

```
nononsense_users_homepage:
path:     /{page}/{query}
defaults: { _controller: NononsenseUserBundle:Users:index, page: 1, query: 'q'}
```

Even if I remove the cache the "hard way" by deleting the app/cache folder it does not matter what I do with the controller I always get the same web page!!

Of course I also used:

```
php app/console cache:clear
```

with equivalent results setting the env flag also.

If I replace my routing with, for example:

```
nononsense_users_homepage:
path:     /{page}/{query}
defaults: { _controller: kkkkkkkkk, page: 1, query: 'q'}
```

The page keeps showing. But if I remove the page or query parts the corresponding twig complains.

I changed other actions and routes in the same bundle and I get the expected results when, for example, I replace a whole action by an exit() call...so it is not I am changing the wrong file :-)

I stopped and run several times the server from the console and I even change browsers and users (you have to be logged to access that page) and nothing changes, there is nothing I can do to get an error page!!!

Nevertheless the action has some DB calls to the UsersRepository and if I include an exit() there I get an empty page as expected.

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you changed the controller in your routing.yml file and the controller does not change, you are probably using a different route.  In dev mode, can you check which route is matched and you will most likely see that a different route is matching causing the error.

Comment: What a silly thing...you were right there were another route that was overwriting it!! I did not notice the controller path in the dev bar.